# Knowing default card from stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent, stripe-payments-js

I am trying to use Stripe API to get users to add payment option. This could be Credit Card or Apple Pay.

The stripe API documentation isn't really clear on how I can retrieve cards and know which is the default card. If anyone has implemented this and has a better explanation how they went about it, I would really appreciate.

Here is how I am adding card currently from fronted (iOS swift) and using NodeJS as backend.

Token is sent from tokenization of card on the client side

```
async addCard(req: Request, token: string) {

        const cardx = await stripe.tokens.retrieve(token);
        return cardx
    }
```

Here is how I retrieve the card details.

```
async getCards(req: Request) {
        const customer = await this.getCardCustomer(req.user);

        const cardsx = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customer.id);
        return cardsx
    }
```

how do I know which card is the default card. Any help is welcomed

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-default_source or https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

Answer (score 0):

After you tokenize the card on the client, you pass the token back to your server and attach it to your Customer object. The simplest way to do this is via the [`source` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-source), which will then automatically set that card as the `default_source` for the Customer. After that, you can [retrieve the Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve) and that indicates the set `default_source`.

Comment: Yeah, that is one way of doing it. It just feels like too many api calls just to retrieve default when a `is_default` field could have been added to the response.